# Measure memory consumption of a Java object (entirely "in application")

Tags: java, memory

For statistics reporting purposes of an application, I want to measure periodically, how much memory (in bytes) an object consumes. I am aware that unlike C/C++, Java does not have a built-in sizeOf() method, but it can be achieved through Java Instrumentation.

However for the application I am developing, there are some constraints;

1. Should not use Java Instrumentation (since the client does not want to have a pre-main and an external agent).
2. Memory measuring algorithm itself should not be memory/time consuming.
3. A qualitative measurement is acceptable, but it should consider the deep-size of an object.

I went through answers for question "[In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)" and even accepted answer suggest Java Instrumentation. Since it is not acceptable in this scenario, I went with [Dimitris Andreou's ObjectExplorer](https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer), which uses a reflection-based object-traversing framework to produce a qualitative measurement. However, that consumes a considerable amount of time and memory when it comes to measuring objects that are around 80MB (deep-size). So my question is is there another way to achieve this, with above constraints?

Comment: Do you have specific constraints on memory/time consumption?

Comment: Not for memory, however the time should be less than 1 second at-least. with Dimitris' ObjectExplorer it takes around 3-5 seconds.